# What's the VS Code LaTeX-Workshop recipe and tools for the Tufte book class?

Tags: tufte, visual-studio-code

### Issue

I'd like to really understand how to use the recipes and tools function for the [LaTeX-Workshop extension](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop) for LaTeX in VS Code. I've read the documentation, but I can't quite figure out how to get it running for the tufte-book class.

As an additional layer of an issue, when I run the recommended commands for the [tufte-book documentation](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex), I get a pile of errors and the pdf doesn't compile.

### Errors

For the following MWE I named `Test.tex`

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\title{Test}
\author{kapple}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
This should work, right?
\end{document}
```

building with the built-in recipe `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex ×2` I get the errors (warnings):

1. shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
2. You have used \nobibliography*
3. File `Test.out` has changed.

When compiling the provided `sample-book.tex` with the same built-in recipe, I get error 1 above, while also:

4. A tonne of `Marginpar on page # moved`.
5. `h` float specifier changed to `ht`.
6. There were undefined citations.
7. The file `sample-book.out` has changed.
8. Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
9. Citation `blah` on page `#` undefined.
10. Reference `blah` on page `#` undefined.
11. And a bunch of under/overfull `\hbox`es.

Even running the document-specified recipe in the terminal, I get a bunch of errors. Should a sample file be that hard to get running?

### Fix Attempt

I've added the following section to settings.json

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
    {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "-pdf",
            "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
            "-shell-escape",
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
            "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "env": {}
    }
],
```

and compiling my MWE `Test.tex` with `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex ×2` results in a pdf produced with errors #2 and #3.

Compiling `sample-book.tex` with `pdflatex ➞ bibtex ➞ pdflatex ×2` results in no pdf produced, error #1 is gone but errors #4 through #11 remain.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a recipe for running `pdflatex` - `bibtex` - `pdflatex` - `pdflatex`? Regarding the errors, you need to tell us exactly which errors (well the first one at least), otherwise no one can guess what is wrong. Edit: I see a recipe like that is included, just hit Ctrl+shift+P, type *build recipe* and you'll find it, hit enter then choose the appropriate recipe.

Comment: Ah, I'll be more verbose about those errors by editing my question. Thanks!

Comment: None of those are errors as far as I can see, they're all warnings, and none of them should prevent a PDF from being created I think. `sample-book.tex` does include a series of images, which has to be placed in a `graphics` subfolder (just as in the GitHub repo), or you need to add the `demo` option to `graphicx` (i.e. `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`), in which case LaTeX won't look for the images, just add a black rectangle.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., that does help. I'm looking to get a smooth experience in compiling a tufte-book document with VSCode. Everytime I add a new part/chapter/section, I get a compile error the first attempt at compiling (and it doesn't produce a pdf), then the second time it finally produces a pdf.